# Workflow for Website based on Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am building an E-commerce website, something like Amazon.com. I am inspired with services and directives provided by **Angular Material**. But i am new to Web technologies and know enough Angular js to make a substantial working one-page website. Can someone please tell me how should I structure a *multi-page* website like amazon?
By this i mean how should go about making a proper directory tree so that all js, css, html and php files are in their proper places.
Shall I build website in modules having a page's js, css ,html and php files in one folder and similarly build other pages by keeping their files in *separate folders*?
I am thinking of having a front-end of my Website to look like Angular material's. Site will have a **side-nav** containing many sections, subsections and filters.
Please pour in your suggestions and the way a proper multi-page website's workflow and structure should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Dude amazon is not something anyone can build, no offence, do u have any idea how big is amazon, i mean structure wise, it is very diffiult to answer this question in one post but u can follow john papas guide on how to structure ur angular application. This could be the starting point for ur project.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I totally understand how huge is Amazon. I am a student and wanted to make a e-commerce website "Just for fun" so that i can be productive during my summer break.